# XML Parsing Error: no element found

Tags: asp.net, javascript, xml, vb.net, formatting

I am using [NiceEdit](http://www.nicedit.com) to format text in text areas, it displays a toolbar over the specified text area, I created a test page, its working, I Response.Write the content of the text area after being formatted, and its okay, I created a break point to see whats being read, it was all fine.

Now I moved to the real page where I should implement this text formatting, it simply did not do anything, the toolbar is shown and its working, but when I submit, nothing is being stored, i created a break point and the content of that text area was nothing, empty "".

I went further and put Response.Write(textArea.text) then Response.End() and I got the error:

XML Parsing Error: no element found

Just in case, the script I am using for the formatting NiceEdit toolbar, and this is the same script i used in my test page and worked just fine, the script is:

```
<script src="../nicEdit/nicEdit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
new nicEditor({buttonList : ['fontSize','fontFamily','fontFormat','bold','italic','underline','strikethrough','forecolor','bgcolor','removeformat'], iconsPath : '../nicEdit/nicEditorIcons.gif'}).panelInstance('txtDescription');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I solved it:
Instead of a Link button, use a Button to save or carry out the action...simple, and illogical for me, but its working :D